# Delete all documents of a type in Amazon Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

How can I delete all documents from a specific type in [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/)?

I used to do that by using the [delete_by_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html) plugin, but Amazon does not allow any custom plugin installation.

Will I really have to do it one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from last month AWS started to support ES5 [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/01/elasticsearch-5-now-available-on-amazon-elasticsearch-service/).

And delete_by_query become a native endpoint on ES5 so you doesn't need custom plugin for deleting docs by query

[delete_by_query docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to run queries against the [DELETE-API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/docs-delete.html), e.g.

```
curl -XDELETE http://<es-node>:9200/<index>/<type>
```

This works fine for us with version 1.7.x in AWS. I know they made some changes how to process deleted data, but this should be working. Your feedback will be appreciated :)

Cheers, Dominik

Comment: Actually we're on 2.3 version and cannot up or downgrade at this moment. Thank you anyway!